# Import data files into iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I tap on attachment in my email and able to import this `dxf` file (`xyz.dxf`) into my application but somehow it is being copied as `rar` file (`xyz.rar`) in the inbox folder. Can any one explain the reason behind this? I tried on Google but couldn't find any information. Hope someone has experienced this format related problem while importing files, like me. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

I am editing the question by providing more information as below:

[image: Plistsnapshot]

**Drawing Interchange File Document type:**

Please refer to the attached picture that indicates that item 0 (Drawing Interchange File) is the one showing problem. If I declare it as "**Document Content Type UTIs\item 0 = public.data**" it does copies the file in the "Document\inbox" folder but the types changes to `RAR` however no change in the file contents.

If I leave it as **public.text type** as in the `plist`, it doesn't import the file into my application at all. If I **only leave "`com.autodesk.dxf`" in the "Document content Type UTIs"** as item 0, then also it doesn't import.

**Typical type:**
It is a custom type file I used only for testing, which is working without any problem, no extension problem etc.

Comment: you should try http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/previewing-and-opening-documents-with-uidocumentinteractioncontroller/

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your question.

Comment: HarshIT, thanks for comment I have seen this link before. My problem doesn't lies here. I am talking about the problem that file from my email gets copied in my app directory in inbox folder but the file format being changed into rar instead of what it has originally.

Comment: Arpit, when I tap on attachment file in my email on my iPhone, the attachment gets opened in my app but when I try to look for the file it's extension is getting modified to rar and not what it has originally in the attachment. This is the problem. I hope it is explained clear to you now.

Comment: Can you post some programming efforts that time when extension of file changes.

Comment: There is no programming needed for that to happen. If you have uti registered in your proplist and you tap such a file, the os copies it into the document/inbox folder in your app. However the handleopenurl function that is used to be implemented is standard. When I get to my MacBook I will post the same but it is all standard that's what I can assure.

Comment: Is it actually a rar archive (which must be defined at attachment content-type header) ?

Comment: Did you try emailing the file and view it on a mac, in Mail, and see what it looks like? On iOS, did you log the size of the file? Is it the same or different?

Comment: ALive I checked in the inbox, the extension only is different. I tried to open the file using a text editor it is same as dxf in my attachment. So the issue really is how this file extension getting changed when importing.

Comment: David I just see the file extension the only difference.

Comment: Just for someone who might have similar problem, I got it fixed by changing the mime type to application/octet-stream.